# How do you use the Radare debugger with command line arguments (parameters)?

Tags: debugging, debuggers, radare2

If I want to debug `ls` I can run,

```
radare -d /bin/ls
```

But, how do I provide an argument or parameter to `ls`? Like I would do if I wanted to run `radare -d /bin/ls -1`. I've tried it like that without quotes, which returns

> radare2: invalid option -- '1'

I've also tried quoting the whole thing

```
radare2 -d "/bin/ls -1"
Could not execvp: No such file or directory
[w] Cannot open 'dbg:///bin/ls\ -1' for writing.
```

[The Radare2book's *"Basic Debugger Session"*](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/introduction/basic_debugger_session.html) says , *"or you can start a new program by specifying its name and parameters"*, but it's not clear how you specify the parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like radare has problems with passing arguments starting with dash ("-"). Please consider [open an issue](https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues).

Anyway, you can pass arguments to radare2 debugged program in several ways.

The simplest way is:

```
r2 -d program arg1 arg2 arg3
```

- **r2** is an alias for radare2.
- **-d** is telling radare2 to debug the execuable.
- **arg1..3** are the arguments passed to the executable by radare2.

For example:

```
$ r2 -d echo Hello, World!
Process with PID 4755 started...
= attach 4755 4755
bin.baddr 0x00400000
Using 0x400000
asm.bits 64
 -- You haxor! Me jane?

[0x7f9b1b000c30]> dc
Hello, World!
```

Another way is using the `ood` command inside radare2 shell:

Execute `radare2 ./program`, then type `ood arg1 arg2 arg3`. The `ood` command is used to "*reopen in debugger mode (with args)*".

```
$ r2 /bin/ls
 -- Use V! to enter into the visual panels mode (dwm style)

[0x004049a0]> doo -la
Process with PID 4757 started...
File dbg:///bin/ls  -la reopened in read-write mode
= attach 4757 4757
4757

[0x7f5f36600c30]> dc
total 206
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root   512 Feb 13 04:25 .
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root   512 Jan 16 05:30 ..
```

You can also call `ood` with dynamic parameters using backticks. For example we want debug our program using the content from a file on our system as an arguments:

```
ood `!cat file.txt`
```

Say file.txt content is 'foo bar' so this equivalent to executing `ood foo bar`

- **backticks** are used for passing the output of radare2 commands.
- **!** is running the given command as in system(3).

Another way to pass arguments to radare2 debugged program is by using `rarun2` profile files:

```
$ r2 -R profile.rr2 -d program
$ cat profile.rr2
#!/usr/bin/rarun2
arg1=foo
arg2=bar
```

- **-R** [rarun2]  specify rarun2 profile to load.

Comment: The last bit of this question seems to be wrong (possibly reporting an old behaviour?)
I found that the correct way of specifying a profile is via `-r`, not `-R`.
`-R` can be used to specify directives without using a file.

In other words: `r2 -r profile.rr2 -d program`

Answer (score 0):

## `rarun2`

This comes under the purview of `rarun2` which isn't documented in the radare2 book, but instead in [radare2-explorations](https://monosource.gitbooks.io/radare2-explorations/content/intro/debugging.html). From `man rarun2`

> The `rr2` (`rarun2`) configuration file accepts the following directives, described as key=value entries and comments defined as lines starting with '#'.
>
> `arg[0-N]`    set value for argument N passed to the program

So you can run that simply by either creating a profile, or doing this

```
r2 -R arg0="-1" -d /bin/ls
```